# How to pass data to navigation drawer item?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

**I am using a nav drawer** with three items(Time sheet, claims, project) and I would like to pass `ab` to claims. In time sheet I have 3 activities, the `ab` is in the work_details activity.How can I do to achieve this?

TimeSheet has 3 activities (Information(extend to fragment),work force,work details)

Claims has 2 activities(claims(extend to fragment), cameraMain).

**WorkDetails.java**

```
  Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
  btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(WorkDetailsTable.this);
                builder.setTitle("Data Saved");
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to save?");
                builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int ii) {
                long ab = ts.insertTimeSheet(name, weather, date, status,b,i);         
               Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
               bundle.putString("ab","ab");
               Claims o=new Claims();
               o.setArguments(bundle);
}
```

**Claims.java**

```
final Long fk=this.getArguments().getLong("ab");
 Button button = (Button) claims.findViewById(R.id.button8);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), CameraMain.class);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), fk+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return claims;
    }
```

I refer from [Send data from activity to fragment in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android) but the app crashed when I select claims item.

> 11-02 09:25:55.910    6116-6116/com.example.project.project
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.project.project, PID: 6116
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.example.project.project.Claims.onCreateView(Claims.java:59)
>               at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
>               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
>               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
>               at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
>               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1453)

I think the NullPointException is came from here

> fk=data.getLong("ab");

Do I need to add the parameter in MainActivity?

**MainActivity.java**

Some part of code snippet in mainActivity

```
 private void selectItem(int position) {

            Fragment fragment = null;

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment=new Information();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment=new Claims();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    fragment=new Project();

                case 3:
                    fragment=new Report();

                case 4:
                    fragment=new ViewView();

                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
                setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

            } else {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
            }
```

**EDITED**

```
 Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(WorkDetailsTable.this);
                builder.setTitle("Data Saved");
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to save?");
                builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int ii) {
               long ab = ts.insertTimeSheet(name, weather, date, status,b,i);
                Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
                bundle.putLong("ab",ab);
                Claims o=new Claims();
                o.setArguments(bundle);
                }
```

**Claims.java**

```
  Bundle bundle=this.getArguments();
  fk=bundle.getLong("ab");
  button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), fk+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                AlertDialogRadio(a1);


            }
        });
```

**MainActivity**

```
  private void selectItem(int position) {

            Fragment fragment = null;

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment=new Information();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment=new Claims();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    fragment=new Project();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    fragment=new Report();
                    break;

                case 4:
                    fragment=new ViewView();

                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                if(fragment instanceof Claims)
                {
                    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("ab","ab");
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                }

                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
                setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

            } else {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In WorkDetails  `Claims fragobj=new Claims();` what happens to this? You seem to set the arguments on an object that you don't use. Try setting arguments from the Activity as that seems to be where you are adding the fragment.

Comment: `Do I need to add the parameter in MainActivity?`
yes, if thats where you create and add the fragment to the fragment manager.

Comment: @MarkusMaga hi..sorry, I don't get it.What should I write in `MainActivity` so that the `ab` can pass to `Claims.java `?

Comment: after `fragment=new Claims();` you can create bundle add ab and set arguments on `fragment`. If you don't have the ab value in main activity you have to send it there first. Is WorkDetails an activity or fragment? How is the flow? Can you add an explaining picture? :) Do you get to claims from WorkDetails through main activity?

Comment: `WorkDetails` is  activity, but `Claims` is  fragment

Comment: You should add a break in case 2,3, and 4 in MainActivity

Comment: Is MainActivity a base class which your other activities extend from?

Comment: @MarkusMaga Nope..`public class WorkDetailsTable extends AppCompatActivity`

Comment: @cricket_007 added..still getting the same result

Comment: @Hoo - I know, just saving you from issues later on once you fix this one  :)

Comment: @cricket_007 ok :)..thanks

Comment: use `bundle.putLong("ab",ab)` instead of `bundle.putString("ab","ab")`

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException`!!!

Comment: I using Toast to display the value fk, but I get 0 although ab not 0...see my edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MainActivity**

```
private void selectItem(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment=new Information();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment=new Claims();
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putLong("ab",WorkDetails.ab);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                break;

            case 2:
                fragment=new Project();
                break;

            case 3:
                fragment=new Report();
                break;

            case 4:
                fragment=new ViewView();

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        } else {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
}
```

**WorkDetails**

```
public static long ab=-1;//this is flied ,don't put in the method



Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new     AlertDialog.Builder(WorkDetailsTable.this);
    builder.setTitle("Data Saved");
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to save?");
            builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int ii) {
           ab = ts.insertTimeSheet(name, weather, date, status,b,i);         

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can just do is to place this data in your activity where fragment is placed. example is.

in your activity
      long ab = 12.4;

in your fragment
     long data = ((YourActivity)getActivity()).ab;

```
     "OR"
```

make ab like

```
static long ab = value; // your Details activity
```

in your details activity and get the value of this

with details activity name like

```
long data = Details.ab //in your claims activity.
```

Comment: Sorry, can you explain more? where should I add? In activity or fragment? Thanks

Comment: You should add this to activity so that all fragments associated with it can get it directly from activity reference.see updated answer an tell me if you there is any problem.

Comment: `YourActivity` mean `WorkDetails` or `Claims` ?

Comment: On which activity your Drawer is ?

Comment: I need to put value ab from `WorkDetails.java` to `Claims` item

Comment: See updated answer now. make your variable static and access it directly

Answer (score 0):

When you are instantiating your Claim Fragment , instantiate a bundle object and assign whatever data that you need to be passed in bundle and set it as argument to the fragment.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putLong("ab",10L);
new Claims().setargument(bundle);
```

Then in your Claim fragment's onCreateView() you can access this bundle data as

```
 Bundle bundle = getArguments();
 long ab = bundle.getLong("ab");
```

Comment: I using Toast to display the value fk, but I get 0 although ab not 0...see my edited post

Comment: you are passing string from main activity and accessing long from your fragment. respect the datatype. Try to send and receive long from both side if you intent to pass long. The above code is a basic way of passing data to fragments, verify you are passing right data and datatype.

Comment: But I cannot use   `bundle.putLong("ab","ab");`..compiler said wrong 2nd argument type

Comment: the second argument is String, so the error pops up. set us long ab = 10L; bundle.putLong("ab",ab);

Comment: But if you refer to my latest edited, I have used long in Claims and WorkDetails, but still cannot use   bundle.putLong("ab","ab") in MainActivity

Comment: "ab" is string, ab is object, try learning basics before codding. Happy Coding :)